# RabbitMQ and persistence (blocking writes?)

Tags: virtualization, nfs, network-attached-storage, rabbitmq

I want to create a RabbitMQ server on a virtual machine (VMware) to be used in production.
It will contain persistent queues.

I'm wondering if it is a bad idea to store the server on a NAS that's accessed over NFS.

Basically my questions are:
Will RabbitMQ's writes be blocking?
Will the entire queue's operation halt on a write?
How much performance degradation should I expect when persisting over NFS?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is a bad idea to use NFS for a database server to reach its hard drive over the network. Either give this VM a local hard drive, or use iSCSI to connect it to your NAS. Any server that needs to persist data is, by definition, a database server.

That said, you could do some testing by routing the VM's connectitivity to the NAS through a Linuc router, which could even be done using a Linux VM and some virtual bridging/switching. Use the [various traffic control tools on Linux](http://linux-ip.net/articles/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/) to make the connection "worse" while you monitor the RabbitMQ broker and the message queues. By doing this you can determine the answers to all of your questions without digging into the internals of RabbitMQ.